# Linking an <img class> image to a URL - working fine in safari and chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, firefox

I'm working on this page:

http://doitanyway.dk/intelligentsystems/en/homeuk/

Just below slider there's 6 images with some layered hover effects. Everything is working like a charm in Safari, Chrome and Opera - but not in Firefox (and Tor).

It seems to be the "a href" wrap round the img class that is the problem. It is not working in my mac Firefox 52.0. Anybody know a workaround...?

Here's the code for the first of the images:

HTML

```
<div class="width: 130px">
<div class="hovereffect">
<a href="http://doitanyway.dk/intelligentsystems/en/healthcare/">
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://doitanyway.dk/intelligentsystems/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/submenu_front1.png" alt="">
</a>
<div class="overlay">
<h2>Healthcare</h2>
<p>
<a href="http://doitanyway.dk/intelligentsystems/en/healthcare/">See our solutions</a>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  .hovereffect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
  background: #000000;
  border-radius: 10px !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px !important;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
pointer-events: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 129px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px !important;
}

.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-filter: sepia(50%); /* Safari */
  filter: sepia(50%);
  max-width: none;
  /* width: calc(100% + 20px);  */
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.7s, transform 0.7s;
  /* -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px,0,0); */
   /* transform: translate3d(-10px,0,0); */
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; 
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px !important;
}

.hovereffect:hover img {
pointer-events: none;
  border-radius: 10px !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px !important;
  opacity: 0.4;
  filter: alpha(opacity=40);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  border-radius: 10px !important;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px !important;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px !important;
}

.hovereffect h2 {
 /*  text-transform: uppercase; */
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 11px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.hovereffect h2:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(-100%,0,0);
}

.hovereffect:hover h2 {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  text-shadow: none;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.hovereffect:hover h2:after {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.hovereffect a, .hovereffect p {
  color: #FFF;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
  font-size: 10px;
}

.hovereffect:hover a, .hovereffect:hover p {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the following css rule.

.hovereffect a, .hovereffect p {opacity:0}

Comment: You're right, it was useless. It does not solve my problem though. Still not working in Firefox.

Comment: In frustration I must have added something that made things worse :-/ 
I tried to restore a copy of my css from a few days back. And after removing .hovereffect a, .hovereffect p {opacity:0} everything worked. Thx a bunch!!!

Answer (score 0):

Which Firefox version is it not working on? It is working on FF 51 for me.
Those attributes might not be supported or, you might need to add an additional -moz-  rule to all of your transforms.
Check support here: http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Comment: I'm on mac FF 52 now and it's not working. The problem seems to be the html - the "a href" wrap round the img class. Anybody know a workaround...?